# Is there a LI equivalent for box-sizing: border-box?

Tags: css, sass

I have a nav bar that consists of an UL with several LI items. The active nav button has a different background color, but I also need a small bottom border on the button.

When applying a border, this appears outside of the LI. When working with divs, you can use `box-sizing:border-box` to get the borders inside the div. But how can you offset the border on a LI item ??? (`list-style-position` seems to have no effect)

My scss code:

```
nav {
  ul {
    li {
      float: left;
      padding: 0;

      box-sizing: border-box;
      list-style-position: inside;

      &.active {
        background-color: white;
        border-bottom: solid 6px blue;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        list-style-position: inside;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you try * { box-sizing:border-box; } ?

Comment: Yes, box-sizing really doesn't work on a LI, even if you use display:block

Comment: Sure it works... when the element has a fixed width and/or height. The element type doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When working with divs, you can use box-sizing:border-box to get the
>   borders inside the div.

To clarify, `box-sizing:border-box` does not make the border to be within the element (change offset), it make the border size be included in the width or height, when set, so i.e. if you give `li` a height of 25px and bottom border 5px, the inner height will decrease to 20px.

> But how can you offset the border on a LI item

You can't offset the border, one workaround to show/hide a border on an element is to use a pseudo element, which will avoid having the element jump/resize when toggle the border, but there are more ways, such as `linear-gradient` (shown in below sample when hover)

```css
body {
  background: lightgray;
}
nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 0 5px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
nav ul li.active::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -6px;
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: solid 6px blue;
  z-index: -1;
}

/*  or one can use linear-gradient  */
nav ul li:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom, white calc(100% - 5px), blue 5px
  ) no-repeat left bottom;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Some text
    </li>
    <li>
      Some text
    </li>
    <li class="active">
      Some text
    </li>
    <li>
      Some text
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

Updated

There is actually a way to offset the border, using `border-image-outset`, shown in this answer:

- [`border-image-outset` in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42300022/border-image-outset-in-css/42301266#42301266)

Comment: Thanks, using pseudo elements works! Although in your example the blue border is actually still below the white box :) I was able to fix the problem even simpler by using an inset box-shadow on the div.

Comment: @Kokodoko I used the border since you asked for the border, and with the `bottom: -6px;` you simply control control whether it should be inside or outside the element ... for this sample I choosed outside since the border size is quite big and almost overlap the text, set it to `bottom: 0;` and it will be inside.

Comment: @Kokodoko I also reread your question and updated my answer with what `box-sizing: border-box` does

Answer (score 1):

Another fast and clean way to create an inside border is to create an **inset shadow without a blur**. You don't even need box-sizing or list-style.

```
nav {
  ul {
    li {
      float: left;
      padding: 0;

      &.active {
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: 0px -6px 0px red inset;
      }
    }
  }
}
```