# border-image-outset in CSS

Tags: html, css

This is how MDN defines [border-image-outset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-outset).

> The border-image-outset property describes by what amount the border
>   image area extends beyond the border box.

What I understood

> Now my image will cover the area border-image-outset + border-width + boder-image-width.

But my example shows me that my understanding is wrong. To simplify, I don't define any border-image-width. We will just make use of border-width + border-image-outset.However, we will use outline shorthand property to see where actual border will lie.

Border image used:

[image]

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Border-image-width</title>
    <style>

        p.ShowingBorderImageOutsetExample{
            border: 1px solid black;
            width:500px;
            border-image-source: url("1.png");
            border-image-slice: 20%;
            border-image-outset: 6;
            outline: 1px solid black;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="ShowingBorderImageOutsetExample">Hi this is just a demo</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The output is as follows:

[image]

The black line is outline. The coloured line is our image border.

The question is should not the image border covers a width of 7px ( 6px of border-image-outline + 1px of border-width) whereas it covers only 1px in output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `border-image-outset` property describes by what amount the border image area extends beyond the border box, but does not define its size, 
`border-width`/`border-image-width` does that.

For `border-image-width`, it defines the width of the border image by defining inward offsets from the border edges. If the `border-image-width` is greater than the `border-width`, then the border image extends beyond the padding (and/or content) edge.

*Or simply put, `border-image-outset` defines how far out border should extend, `border-width` and `border-image-width` defines its size (width of the border).*

Since you only gave the border a size of 1px, and no `border-image-width`, that is how it will render, and if you give it 6px, and set the outset to the same, you'll get this, first `p`. In second `p`, where the outset is 12px, and the `border-image-width` is set to 12px, it will render all the way to the outline.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Border-image-width</title>
    <style>

        p.ShowingBorderImageOutsetExample{
            border: 6px solid black;
            width:500px;
            border-image-source: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/syjY3.png");
            border-image-slice: 20%;
            border-image-outset: 6px;
            outline: 1px solid black;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }

        p.ShowingBorderImageOutsetExample2{
            border: 6px solid black;
            width:500px;
            border-image-source: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/syjY3.png");
            border-image-slice: 20%;
            border-image-width: 12px;
            border-image-outset: 12px;
            outline: 1px solid black;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="ShowingBorderImageOutsetExample">Hi this is just a demo</p>
<p class="ShowingBorderImageOutsetExample2">Hi this is just a demo</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry I still did not get you. Border-image-outset defines more space where an image can extend beyond border. Now, in my example , I have defined the border-width 1px. border-image-width default value is 1 and border-image-outset as 6 = 6px in my example. So image should be stretched in area 7px ( 6px outside + 1 px of border width ) ? Please ignore corners and all that for now to simplify discussion.

Comment: @BreakingBenjamin `border-image-outset` defines not space, but how far out border should extend, `border-width` and `border-image-width` defines the size (width of the border)